# alert a value from a cloned link being wrapped by a cloned phrase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning everyone,

I tried to sleep over my problem, but I am stuck at the syntax as I'm relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery.

So, my idea was to clone a phrase like:

```
<p>
 <a href="#" class="myClass">[1]</a>
</p>
```

This is my code to clone this phrase:

```
var clone = $("p").clone();
```

Now I want to add a checkbox to each phrase

```
var clone = $("p").clone().prepend("<input type='checkbox' id='checked' checked>");
```

The html-structure looks like:

```
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" checked=" " id="checked">
 <a href="#" class="myClass">[1]</a>
</p>
```

The following is the hardest part for me:
I'm trying to achieve an alert with the value of the link, when the checkbox is marked.
The value should have no brackets like "[" or "]".
I guess that I have to work with regular expressions like replace();

My final aim would be to insert the value of the link into a textarea.
But I didn't figure out how to alert the value.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like:

```
var clone = $("p").clone().prepend($('<input>', {
     id:      'checked',
     type:    'checkbox',
     checked: 'checked',
     change:  function() {
         if( this.checked ) {
             alert( $(this).next('a').text().match(/^\[(\d+)\]$/)[1] );
         }
     }
})).appendTo(document.body /* or somewhere else */);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/WkceQ/

Comment: That's cool. Your fiddle works. But I have to use the 1.2.6 jQuery library. I can't use sth. like id: 'checked'. I would put the id, the type and the status into the input element and create a function on change. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a.go').click(function(){
    var $p = $('p');
    $p.each(function(){
        var checked = ($(this).find('input').is(':checked'));
        var result = checked ? ($(this).find('a')[0].innerHTML.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) : $(this).find('a')[0].innerHTML;
        alert(result)
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MXPg3/)**